# Controlar paginacion de una api Node.js, Express y MongoDB

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, express

Quisiera saber como controlar cuando se termina la paginación de comentarios en el front, para poder controlarla y devolver un mensaje, o devolver otra cosa. Un saludo.

Este es mi código.

```
Comentario.aggregate([
query,
{ $sort: { createdAt: -1 } },
{ $skip: parseInt(offset) },
{ $limit: parseInt(limite) },
])
```

El código anterior me duevuelve el número de comentarios con un limite. Mi pregunta es como controlar en el frontend cuando la base de datos alcance el limite de comentarios y no haya mas que mostrar.

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a [es.SO], podrías ser mas especifico de que es lo que quieres lograr? a que te refieres con "saber como controlar cuando se termina la paginacion"? dices que para poder devolver un mensaje, pero en tu código muestras un consulta de mongo, procura añadir la mayor cantidad de información relevante posible para poder ayudarte. Te podría ayudar hacer el recorrido por [ask]

Comment: La paginación se termina cuando la consulta devuelve menos documentos que `limit`. Eso es lo que debes controlar. Saludos

Comment: Muchas gracias Mauricio, lo logré controlar como tu dijiste. Un saludo.